# multiple AVPlayer instances pause simultaneously causes momentary but annoying freeze

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, multithreading, avplayer

I am implementing a UICollectionView that consists of multiple square AVPlayerLayers, 3 on each row, that fills the entire screen. All players play at the same time. When user scrolls the collection view, I had to reset the url of the AVPlayer in each reusable cell (so 3 at a time). According to my observation, the reset is equivalent to pausing the videos, and each pause will block UI on the main thread. Blocking it 3 three times when 3 reusable cells are redefined means very glitchy scrolling experience.

I also noticed that the pausing cannot be done threads other than the main. I am not particular knowledgable in dealing with memory I/O, but I am assuming the glitch is due to sudden dump of quite a lot stuff in memory. So I am wondering if there is any other way to handle this so the code offers a smooth scrolling experience.

Comment: Good question. I had the same issue which I didnt find a solution. Ended up using a shared Player and only 1 cell playing at a time. Hope someone comes up with a solution

Comment: Here's my latest iteration of a perfectly smooth-scrolling collection view with real-time video previews (up to 16 at a time:  https://youtu.be/7QlaO7WxjGg  It even uses a cover flow custom layout and "reflection" view that mirrors the video preview perfectly.  The source code is here:  http://www.mediafire.com/download/ivecygnlhqxwynr/VideoWallCollectionView.zip

Answer (score 0):

No, if while scrolling you are not creating any player object scrolling will be fine, but if you are creating player object then scrolling will be the issue ?

Comment: i am not creating new player objects. I am simply reseting the url of the existing player. setting the url, as far as I'm concerned, is the reason it's glitchy, because it pauses the video, and it takes a lot of memory writing to do so.

Comment: Can you put in your code what you are doing to reuse the player ?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to find your answer using a different approach to adding the AVPlayerLayers to cells. Although I just finished this today—and, consequently, scrolling is not smooth yet—I know that this makes more sense than putting the AVPlayer... code in the cell subclass:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UICollectionViewCell *cell = (UICollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Enumerate array of visible cells' indexPaths to find a match
if ([self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems
     indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(NSIndexPath * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
         return (obj.item == indexPath.item);
     }]) dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [self drawLayerForPlayerForCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
     });


    return cell;
}

- (void)drawPosterFrameForCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self.imageManager requestImageForAsset:AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.assetsFetchResults[indexPath.item]
                                                          targetSize:AssetGridThumbnailSize
                                                         contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill
                                                             options:nil
                                                       resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {
                                                           cell.contentView.layer.contents = (__bridge id)result.CGImage;
                                                       }];
}

- (void)drawLayerForPlayerForCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.contentView.layer.sublayers = nil;
    [self.imageManager requestPlayerItemForVideo:(PHAsset *)self.assetsFetchResults[indexPath.item] options:nil resultHandler:^(AVPlayerItem * _Nullable playerItem, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if([[info objectForKey:PHImageResultIsInCloudKey] boolValue]) {
                [self drawPosterFrameForCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
            } else {
                AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:[AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem]];
                [playerLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
                [playerLayer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
                [playerLayer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
                [playerLayer setFrame:cell.contentView.layer.bounds];
                [cell.contentView.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
                [playerLayer.player play];
            }
        });
    }];
}
```

Note that the drawPosterFrameForCell method places an image where a video cannot be played because it is stored on iCloud, and not the device.